# How to use TreeView in WinUI Uno Platform app

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, uno-platform, winui

I'm struggling to implement a WinUI3 TreeView in a WinUI3 Uno Platform app.
The problem is that despite using the code provided by the Uno Platform playground or the winui3 gallery apps, the frame where it should be displayed does not show anything.

So the question is:

Can I use TreeView with unoplatform? If yes, how?

Thank you all.

The both codes that I've tried (and the only ones that ?I've been able to find are:

This one from WinUI 3 Gallery:

```
<Page x:Class="AppUIBasics.ControlPages.TreeViewPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:AppUIBasics"
      xmlns:controlpages="using:AppUIBasics.ControlPages"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate"
                      x:DataType="controlpages:ExplorerItem">
            <TreeViewItem AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Name}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" IsExpanded="True">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="20" Source="../Assets/folder.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate"
                      x:DataType="controlpages:ExplorerItem">
            <TreeViewItem AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Name}">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="20" Source="../Assets/file.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>

        <controlpages:ExplorerItemTemplateSelector 
            x:Key="ExplorerItemTemplateSelector"
            FolderTemplate="{StaticResource FolderTemplate}"
            FileTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <local:ControlExample HeaderText="A simple TreeView with drag and drop support">
            <local:ControlExample.Example>
                <Grid Height="400" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TreeView x:Name="sampleTreeView" MinWidth="345" MaxHeight="400" Margin="0,12,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemInvoked="sampleTreeView_ItemInvoked" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True" />
                </Grid>
            </local:ControlExample.Example>
            <local:ControlExample.Xaml>
                <x:String>
                    &lt;TreeView  CanDragItems="True"  AllowDrop="True"/&gt;
                </x:String>
            </local:ControlExample.Xaml>
        </local:ControlExample>

        <local:ControlExample HeaderText="A TreeView with Multi-selection enabled">
            <local:ControlExample.Example>
                <Grid Height="400" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TreeView x:Name="sampleTreeView2" MinWidth="345" MaxHeight="400" Margin="0,12,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
                </Grid>
            </local:ControlExample.Example>
            <local:ControlExample.Xaml>
                <x:String>
                    &lt;TreeView SelectionMode="Multiple" /&gt;
                </x:String>
            </local:ControlExample.Xaml>
        </local:ControlExample>

        <local:ControlExample HeaderText="A TreeView with DataBinding Using ItemSource" XamlSource="TreeView\TreeViewDataBindingSample_xaml.txt">
            <local:ControlExample.Example>
                <Grid Height="400" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TreeView x:Name="TreeView1" 
                                          MinWidth="345" 
                                          MaxHeight="400" 
                                          Margin="0,12,0,0"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind DataSource}">
                        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="controlpages:ExplorerItem">
                                <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" Content="{x:Bind Name}" IsExpanded="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeView>
                </Grid>
            </local:ControlExample.Example>
        </local:ControlExample>

        <local:ControlExample HeaderText="A TreeView with ItemTemplateSelector" XamlSource="TreeView\TreeViewTemplateSelectorSample_xaml.txt">
            <local:ControlExample.Example>
                <Grid Height="400" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TreeView x:Name="FileTree" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="345" MaxHeight="400" Margin="0,12,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DataSource}" 
                            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerItemTemplateSelector}" />
                </Grid>
            </local:ControlExample.Example>
        </local:ControlExample>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

And this one from the Uno Platform Playground:

```
<muxc:TreeView x:Name="DessertTree" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <muxc:TreeView.RootNodes>
        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Flavors" IsExpanded="True">
            <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Vanilla"/>
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Strawberry"/>
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Chocolate"/>
            </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
        </muxc:TreeViewNode>

        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Toppings">
            <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Candy">
                    <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Chocolate"/>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Mint"/>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Sprinkles"/>
                    </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                </muxc:TreeViewNode>
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Fruits">
                    <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Mango"/>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Peach"/>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Kiwi"/>
                    </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                </muxc:TreeViewNode>
                <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Berries">
                    <muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Strawberry"/>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Blueberry"/>
                        <muxc:TreeViewNode Content="Blackberry"/>
                    </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
                </muxc:TreeViewNode>
            </muxc:TreeViewNode.Children>
        </muxc:TreeViewNode>
    </muxc:TreeView.RootNodes>
</muxc:TreeView>
```

And both of them do exactly the same: Even though they compile, there is nothing displayed, as if the xaml archives were empty.

Comment: You should be able to use ``TreeView`` in Uno. Can you check if you can make this code work in a regular WinUI 3 project?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and the one from WinUI 3 Gallery forks perfectly fine. The TreeView is implemented in Uno, or at least they say that in their web. But as I said even though it compiles the page doesn't show anything.

Comment: Update: The code seems to work in a wpf uno platform app, but not in my winui3 app. Does someboady know if it should be able to kork or if it is not supported yet?

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly your issue is and what you tried? According to their documentation and repository, TreeView is supported.